# htaccess rewrite url to resource and display clean url

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have urls in the following pattern that point to static html resources:

`/1-process.html` or

`/2-process-details.html`

I am trying to rewrite the urls to exclude the numbered prefix and file extension, the above becoming:

`/process/`

`/process-details/`

I am able to rewrite the url to show in the browser the clean url, but the html resource is of course not found.
I want to retain the file naming structure but clean it up on the url side. Is this possible?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^([1-9]-)(.*)\.html$ /$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Why mark this question down with giving a valid reason? The purpose of this question is to learn more about the how to craft the required url in any situation. There is a valid reason for this question.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the question itself contains enough detail to be answered. However, there is no way for Apache to guess which number to use when rewriting back to the existing file... The only thing I could suggest is to use [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html). Though, you may find that to be somewhat tedious. As such, a better recommendation (as you'd probably have already guessed) is to strip out the numbers from the actual file names and proceed from there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That is what I wanted to know. I was hoping that there was some way of storing the numbers in a (catch-like) variable during the condition rule. But you are saying that is not possible.